# Can not Instantiate Custom Salesforce Objects

Tags: c#, wsdl, salesforce, enterprise

I was able to download and include both the partner and enterprise WSDLs into my VS .NET 2010 project. In the Web References folder, all that appears is a `Reference.map` file, which, when I expand, exposes a few other `.datasource` files but no class stubs.

After including a reference to both APIs, I can not create an instance of my Salesforce classes (both native [such as Account] and custom). I need to do this for an `upsert()`.

Is there something I am missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't typically need both the Partner and the Enterprise WSDL in the same project.

The Enterprise WSDL will be tailored to the schema of the generating Org and will have classes for Account, Contact etc and include properties for custom fields.

The Partner WSDL is designed to work with any Org, so it doesn't have specific classes. Instead you use a generic sObject and access XML Elements for the field values.